# Проверка на наличие процесса

Tags: delphi, winapi, процесс, x86-64

- Delphi XE 10.2.3

Нужно проверить наличие (или отсутствие) процесса.
Например есть процесс *Wireshark.exe* и нужно при его наличии вырубать программу.

Просмотрел тонну страниц - там все для *x86* битной системы, а мне нужна подобная функция на x64

Comment: Скрипт на вырубание программы не нужен

Comment: Нужна boolean функция ProccessExists(S: String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение.
И с 64 бит отлично работает `TLHELP32`

Вот код:

```
Function IsProcesssRun(processname: string): boolean;
var 
  Snapshot: Thandle;
  proc: TprocessEntry32;
begin
  result := false;

  Snapshot := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

  if snapshot = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then 
    exit;

  proc.dwSize := sizeof(TprocessEntry32);
  if Process32First(snapshot, proc) then
  repeat
    if proc.szExeFile = processname then
    begin
      result := true;
      break;
    end;
  until not process32next(snapshot, proc);

  CloseHandle(snapshot);
end;
```